# Given a "pledge" to complete each day, what words can represent success and failure in a motivating fashion?

Tags: synonyms

If one decides that they are going to attempt to complete a pledge or task each day, what are two words (one for each) that can be used to represent the number of successes and failures, without being too discouraging?

Example pledge: "I'm going to exercise 20 minutes every day."

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I think judgment about what is or is not discouraging may be a matter of opinion; I see nothing wrong with  using "failure" for myself, but others may disagree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Success:
I met/reached my goal today

Failure:
I missed today's opportunities to exercise.
My goal evaded me.

Comment: Hmm I think met / missed is the way to go. Thanks!